# Calculate mean of multiple lists with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, plot

Assume I have the following lists (can be more than three lists):

```
l1 = [4,5,10,20,13]
l2 = [3,7,11]
l3 = [10,40,50,60]
```

how can I calcuate the mean per items for these lists as follow considering they have different lengths?

```
avg = [(4+3+10)/3, (5+7+40)/3, (10+11+50)/3, (20+?+60)/3, (13+?+?)/3 ]
```

The avg can be used to plot the mean of those lists.
One idea is to truncate all to length of shortest list, but there should be a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just do `means = [sum(lst) / len(lst) for lst in (l1, l2, l3)]`

Answer (score 1):

In pure Python, this is a job for `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
def column_wise_sum(rows):
    columns = zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue=0)
    return [sum(col)/len(rows) for col in columns]
```

Step-by-step:

```
In [15]: rows = [ 
    ...:     [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    ...:     [2, 4], 
    ...:     [3, 3, 3] 
    ...: ]                                                                                 

In [16]: list(zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue=0))                                                
Out[16]: [(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 3), (3, 0, 3), (4, 0, 0)]

In [17]: [sum(column)/len(rows) for column in zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue=0)]                   
Out[17]: [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your lists in one big list-of-lists, one solution would be:

```
l1 = [4,5,10,20,13]
l2 = [3,7,11]
l3 = [10,40,50,60]

ls = [l1, l2, l3]

pd.DataFrame(ls).mean(axis = 1)
```